# Flatlist Multiple item Selection not working on React Native

Tags: react-native, multi-select, react-native-flatlist

I am creating a multi-select grid Flatlist and it seems to work fine in IOS phone but it doesn't work at all on Android phone. On IOS it can select an item when clicked, but on Android it just flickers when you select/click an item.

I am really, really can't figure it out. Please help.

Thank you,

[Flatlist-Grid as per code][1]

```
import {
    View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView,
    Image,
} from 'react-native'
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class StoreSelector extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            dataList: [
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#ffsdsf', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#01713f', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#fsdaff', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#00b0a6', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#ffgadsf', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#fdfdf', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#fsdff', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#ec008c', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#005baa', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#fceff', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#ffwf', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#000', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
                { name: 'exp: date', key: '#ea3440', image: <Image style={{ height: 110, width: 110, backgroundColor: 'red' }} /> },
            ]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let arr = this.state.dataList.map((item, index) => {
            this.isSelected = false
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ dataList: arr })
    }

    selectionHandler = (ind) => {
        const { dataList } = this.state
        let arr = dataList.map((item, index) => {
            if (ind == index) {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
            }
            return { ...item }
        })
        this.setState({ dataList: arr })
    }


    render() {

        const { dataList } = this.state

        return (
            <View style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                <ScrollView >
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        {
                            dataList.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                        key={item.key}
                                        onPress={() => this.selectionHandler(index)}
                                        style={styles.boxContainer}>
                                        <View style={styles.img}>{item.image}</View>
                                        <View>{item.isSelected ? <MaterialIcons name="check-box" size={24} color="#fbbe2f" /> : <MaterialIcons name="check-box-outline-blank" size={24} color="grey" />}</View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                )

                            })
                        }
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </View>

        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        alignItems: 'center',

    },
    boxContainer: {
        height: 110,
        width: 110,
        margin: 7,

    },
    img: {
        elevation: 5,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: .3,
        shadowRadius: 3,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#eee'
    }

})


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrRVS.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given elevation to image element which is appearing above your checkbox so on select action it gets selected but not visible as it is under the image.

Now question is how will you see the checkbox?

Option 1: Remove the elevation

```
img: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 1, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: .3,
        shadowRadius: 3,
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#eee'
    }
```

Option 2: Make the elevation of the icons higher then the image elevation

```
<View>
 {item.isSelected ? 
   <MaterialIcons name="check-box" size={24} color="#fbbe2f" style={{elevation:10}}/> 
    : 
  <MaterialIcons name="check-box-outline-blank" size={24} color="grey"  style={{elevation:10}}/>}
</View>
```

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!  Thank you so much!! 
I am so happy I could cry! It's been days battling this. 
IT WORKS!!!!!!!